# Force image to save when clicking on download link

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, themes

I am using a wordpress theme that show images in lightbox when clicking on theme, but it also do it for links, I want to kip the lightbox for the images, but offer to download when clicking on download link, the theme I am using is [baic](http://themify.me/demo/#theme=basic) from [themify](http://themify.me/) 
and here one option inside the theme, when deactivated it just open the image in new window
[image]

here a link http://bit.ly/1xG2dQC to the page I am working on, you can see the download link under the image 
thanks

Comment: Looks like you want the _download_ HTML attribute

Comment: I add it but it didn't work